# Excel VBA error: "Compile error: Expected: end of statement"

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to do some very basic stuff with VBA in Excel (2010) for a user form.

I have the following as my 1st and only line of code so far (I'm trying to define an integer for a loop):

```
dim i as integer = 1
```

when I press enter at the end of the line I get the following error:

> Compile error: Expected: end of statement

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Dim i As Integer = 1` is not syntactically valid in VBA and that's confusing the interpreter.

You need to write

```
Dim i As Integer
i = 1
```

instead.

Note also that the *range* of an `Integer` in VBA is -32768 to +32767. Most folk use a `Long` instead.

Comment: That with the long might be true, but theres no reason to use it over an integer for normal reasons

Comment: Also, extra note, Dim i as Integer = 1 is valid VB.NET, but not vba, just as you mentioned

Answer (score 0):

If you want `i` to always equal `1`, then you could write:

```
Const i as Integer = 1
```

But since you write you are defining it for a loop, Bathsheba's syntax is better, or you could do

```
Dim i as integer
For i = 1 to n
   do something
next i
```